# How to update the current session when updating an array with mongoose push. Using express handlebars mongoose and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am currently trying to create a social media app, where you can only see posts of your friends and direct message only with friends. Unfortunately when adding a friend by updating the database with mongoose by pushing an item into a friends array (which works perfectly). when i then visit posts or messages, the friends has not been updated and requires logging out and then logging in again, which updates it to work exactly how I envisioned. Is this something to do with the way that the friends array is being updated?

The friends update array:

```
const User = require("../models/user");

const FriendsController = {
  Update: (req, res) => {
    const requesterUserID = req.session.user._id
    const receiverUserID = req.params.userID

    User.findOne({ _id: receiverUserID }).then((user) => {
      user.friends.push(requesterUserID);
      user.save(() => {
        User.findOne({ _id: requesterUserID}).then(user2 => {
          user2.friends.push(receiverUserID)
          user2.save(() => {
            res.redirect(`/profile/${receiverUserID}`);
          });
        })
      });
    });
  }
};

module.exports = FriendsController;
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on. I am assuming it is related to the session given the fact that it works upon refreshing the session by logging out and logging in again.

The session controller:

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const SessionsController = {
  New: (req, res) => {
    res.render("sessions/new", {});
  },

  Create: (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((result) => {
          if (result) {
            req.session.user = user;
            res.redirect("/posts");
          } else {
            res.render("sessions/new", { signInError: true });
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.render("sessions/new", { signInError: true });
      }
    });
  },

  Destroy: (req, res) => {
    console.log("logging out");
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
      res.clearCookie("user_sid");
    }
    res.redirect("/sessions/new");
  },
};

module.exports = SessionsController;
```

clearing cookie upon logging out:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.cookies.user_sid && !req.session.user) {
    res.clearCookie("user_sid");
  }
  next();
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: By the sounds of it, you have the authenticated user cached. When you add friends, you are adding them to the database, but not updating the friends list of the cached user.

Comment: Ah, okay, I am relatively new, only been coding for a few months now. How do I update the cached user?

Comment: It may be as simple as doing `req.session.user = user;` again after all of the saving has succeeded in your `FriendsController.update`.